# C function checks if element is member of linked list (return 0 if true, return 1 if false)

Tags: c

Here below is my code

```
int isMember(struct DLinkedList **first, struct DLinkedList *el)
{
    struct DLinkedList* temp = *first;
    
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        if (temp->sensorData == el)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        temp = temp->next;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

For the arguments of the function I am supposed to use double pointer on first and a pointer to the element as in *el (not int)
Now I believe that I have written a correct body for the function but I am still getting an error.
The error says

error: invalid operands to binary == (have 'double' and 'struct DLinkedList *')

If there are other mistakes in my code please let me know since the compiler does not point out everything.

Comment: What's wrong with the answer legoscia gave? It seems to perfectly address the issue.

Comment: @klutt I have fixed the syntax error with legscia's help, however when I run the program it is not printing 0 or 1. I am expecting it to print 0 since I have included `el` in the list.

Comment: This site is not intended for iterative problem solving. If you change your code you invalidate answers that have already been posted. Please don't do that. Post a new question instead. I have rolled back your edit.

Comment: @klutt I have not removed my old question, I clearly wrote Edit and wrote down the new code without removing the old one, if this is what you meant.

Comment: It does not matter. Edits are for clarifications. Not alterations and iterative solving.

Comment: And yes, you did remove the old code. You replaced `== el` with `== el->sensorData` which is exactly what @legoscia said in their answer.

Comment: And a rhetorical question. The function `isMember` does not have any print statement. Nor do you have any print statement that depend on the return value of the function. Why do you expect it to print 1 or 0 when there is absolutely no code that tries to do that particular thing?

Comment: So to print 1 or 0, you can use `printf("%d\n", isMember(&first, el);`

Comment: @klutt, thanks man. I'm new to this site so I've probably unwillingly made some mistakes. It worked with the last suggestion, I thought that since I am using return 0/return 1 that I wouldn't need to print it out and that C does it on its own.

Comment: I've noticed that you're new. That's why I'm teaching you how to use this site. ;)

Comment: And C does not do ANYTHING on it's own.

Comment: @klutt I have programmed in Java last year (I don't remember much of it) but there were some features that Java provided, unlike C. Thanks for all the info :)

Comment: Ok, if you come from Java, then you have one VERY important concept to learn, and that is *undefined behavior*. It means that your program can behave in whatever way it likes. Including working the way it should. UB is invoked when Java would have thrown an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`el` is the link node, not the sensor data you want to compare. Try this:

```
if (temp->sensorData == el->sensorData)
```

Another thing that's odd with the code is that it returns 0 if it finds a matching element and 1 if not, but the name `isMember` suggests that it should be the other way around. Consider what would happen if you called the code like this:

```
if (isMember(...))
{
    /* is there a matching element in this case? */
}
else
{
    /* or in this case? */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @legoscia, but our teacher has instructed us to return 0 if we find a match, otherwise return 1. I agree, it is odd but that is how she wants it.

Comment: By the way, when I call the function in my main, is it correct to do it like this: isMember(&first, 5);

Comment: @Maso When you ask a question like that, you really have to think things through. What do you expect it to do if you call it like that? What do you think it will do if `el`  is/isn't a member? Hint: You're completely ignoring the return value.

Comment: @klutt You are correct, I changed it to isMember(&first, el). Is this what you meant by me ignoring the return value? I have written inside my if statement that if the `el` is found `return 0;`

Comment: @Maso *but our teacher has instructed us to return 0 if we find a match, otherwise return 1. I agree, it is odd but that is how she wants it*  And your teacher just failed a code review at any organization that cares about readable and maintainable code.  Having a function called `ismember()` return ***FALSE*** when it actually does find a member is nonsensical.  Because `0` in C ***is*** false - literally.  If her goal is to teach you how to identify crap/garbage code, she's succeeding by example.